# Restrict records returned by view with group by rollup whilst modifying totals

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a view that has an average for some columns. This view will be accessed by month and year and I would like to create it as global (full table scan) and later use with different condition such as: Month 05 Year 2015 / Month 04 Year 2015

Right now I have created it like this:

```
create or replace view view_x_tipology as
select dt_ref, gg_ref, mm_ref, yyyy_ref, avg(pcr_qt) pcr_tot, avg(ltr_qt) ltr_tot, avg(tbr_qt) tbr_tot, avg(qt_total) day_total
  from stock_base
 group by rollup (dt_ref, gg_ref, mm_ref, yyyy_ref)
```

My main problem is that the grand total (I don't need sub totals) has only the three total with a value, and all the other fields is null

```
DT_REF      GG_REF MM_REF  YYYY_REF   PCR_TOT     LTR_TOT     TBR_TOT     TOT 
28/05/2015  28     5       2015       118654      9433        19729       147816        
28/05/2015  28     5                  118654      9433        19729       147816        
28/05/2015  28                        118654      9433        19729       147816        
28/05/2015                            118654      9433        19729       147816        
29/05/2015  29     5       2015       132132      10022       19687       161841        
29/05/2015  29     5                  132132      10022       19687       161841        
29/05/2015  29                        132132      10022       19687       161841        
29/05/2015                            132132      10022       19687       161841        
                                      125393      9727,5      19708       154828,5
```

For example, I would like to query `view_x_tipology` in this way:

```
select *
  from view_per_tipology
 where mm_ref = 5
  and yyyy_ref = 2015
```

With this query, I need all days in 05/2015 with the last line with the average

**UPDATE**

As Ben said, i cant create a view with rollup that do this, i've used a simple union to calculate the average. Sure, this only work for months and year.

```
select dt_ref, gg_ref, mm_ref, yyyy_ref, pcr_qt, ltr_qt, tbr_qt, qt_total
  from stock_base
union
select null, null, mm_ref, yyyy_ref, avg(pcr_qt), avg(ltr_qt), avg(tbr_qt), avg(qt_total)
      from stock_base
     group by rollup (dt_ref, gg_ref, mm_ref, yyyy_ref)
```

The field qt_* on stock_base have already the sum of the day/month/year.
In union, i simply use AVG function to create the average.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't... you're attempting to query data that doesn't exist. If you try to work around this by doing something like the following the total will still apply to your entire, original, result-set.

```
select *
  from view_per_tipology
 where ( mm_ref = 5 and yyyy_ref = 2015 )
    or dt_ref is null
```

You're going to have to write the query out each time. Alternatively, if you *always* want the current month, you can restrict your view to only contain this data.

Comment: HI Ben look at my update, if you think this is correct, i will change it as an answer